# SSAS ROLAP dimension isn't processed until manually browsed

Tags: sql-server, ssas, rolap

I'm converting an existing SSAS project to use proactive caching, and I've run into an issue when I attempt to query the cubes.

I've converted the dimensions to ROLAP, and the measure groups to HOLAP.  When I query the cubes, I get a "key not found" error on the dimensions.  If I browse the dimension, then query the cube again, the query runs fine.

It seems like the dimension isn't being processed until it's directly queried, even if I run a "Process Full" on the database.

Is there any way to indicate a dimension should be processed before a measure?  I would expect SSAS to handle that automatically, but it doesn't seem like it does.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a synchronization issue. Rolap will be taking you straight to the data source whilst holap will be processed  in the background until data is available.

Try using the same storage for both to see if this problem is alleviated

Comment: Using ROLAP everywhere doesn't seem to have made a difference.